# Vilna Gaon - Mitzvah Goreres Mitzvah

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, pirke-avot-ethicsof, vilna-gaon

I once heard (I do not recall from who or where) that The Vilna Gaon once remarked that the way to determine if one's actions were in fact a good deed, one must look at the after effects. The Gr"a is interpreting the Mishna in Pirkei Avot: מצוה גוררת מצוה – one mitzvah leads to another mitzvah.

Does anyone know where such a Gr"a can be found.

Or if this is mis-attributed to the Gra, and really someone else said this.

Or maybe someone has heard a similar idea from somewhere else.

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45941&st=&pgnum=44  this is the GRA on the Mishna in hebrew books, I don't see this perush

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=Rr4pAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94+%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8%D7%AA+%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94+%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9+%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8%22%D7%90&source=bl&ots=A85TSvZBOF&sig=C2x85QA2KmQAz-7YXDOeTaAvgbA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLhu_2o63UAhWBNT4KHcWUCVIQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q=%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94%20%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94%20%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8%22%D7%90&f=false